# Is it possible to determine the ASP.NET Core hosting environment in an HTML helper method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, html-helper

I'm writing an HTML helper method in ASP.NET Core and I want to detect the current hosting environment.  The given way to do this is using DI, for example:

```
public class MyClass {
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public MyClass(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment) {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public void Xyzzy() {
        var environment = _hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
        [...]
    }
}
```

However HTML helper methods are extension methods and must therefore be static, so DI can't be used.  I can't seem to see anything in the `IHtmlHelper` object that tells me the current hosting environment; how can I find it from my HTML helper method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IHtmlHelper` has a [`ViewContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper.viewcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Rendering_IHtmlHelper_ViewContext) property, which itself has a [`HttpContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actioncontext.httpcontext?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ActionContext_HttpContext) property. With this, you can use [`GetRequiredService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.serviceproviderserviceextensions.getrequiredservice?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to get hold of `IHostingEnvironment`. Here's an example:

```
htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
    .GetRequiredService<IHostingEnvironment>();
```

This isn't DI: it's using the Service Locator pattern, which is often called an [antipattern](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). If you want to use DI, consider creating a [Tag Helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?view=aspnetcore-3.0) instead of an `IHtmlHelper` extension method. That would also mitigate the need to nest all of those property access calls.